# Enterprise Architect Sequencing With Python

Tags: python, enterprise-architect

I am starting to use Python for automating Enterprise Architect. I am unable to change the sequencing of an element with the code below. What am I doing wrong? What is the good way of using DiagramObjects.Sequence?

```
TestDiagEl=diagram.DiagramObjects.AddNew(<validlocation>,"ArchiMate_Capability")
TestDiagEl.Sequence="99"
TestDiagEl.Update()
TestDiagEl.ElementID=element1.ElementID
TestDiagEl.Update()
eaRep.ReloadDiagram(diagram.DiagramID)
```

Comment: Why do you have two calls to Update? Are you trying to update the sequence before setting the ElementID? Because that would lead to an error. You can't save a DiagramObject without ElementID

Comment: Should i "AddNew> ElementID > Update >  Sequence >Update   ?

Comment: Why do you do two updates? For each line of code you should know exactly why you are writing it, otherwise you are doing *programming by incantation*. Another one, what's the reason for the `ArchiMate_Capability` parameter you pass to the `AddNew` method?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first `Update` since at that position the important reference `ElementID` is not set and EA will run into trouble.

Further the 2nd parameter of `AddNew` is supposed to be an empty string. Not sure what EA will do with it, if you supply something else.

Finally `Sequence` is `int` and not `string` (though Python is forgiving in such cases as I have just tested and it will internally do `int(<parameter>)` which then might raise an exception).

Comment: Also: the property Sequence is a Long, not a string, so it will error when passing a string. Pfew, 6 lines, 3 errors, that's 50%

Comment: @GeertBellekens Correct. I think that Python will do the casting automagically but not 100% sure. Will amend my answer.

Comment: TestDiagEl=diagram.DiagramObjects.AddNew(generatePosString(l,r,t,b),"")
            TestDiagEl.ElementID=element1.Elements.GetAt(sayici).ElementID
            TestDiagEl.Update()
            eaRep.ReloadDiagram(diagram.DiagramID)   i did the changes that you guys asked. AFAIK int() casts to long for Python. This didnot resolve my problem I still get the exact same reults as the question.

Comment: Well, lots of reasons can be the cause. Don't expect someone to be clairevoyant.

Comment: Is there a way that you can provide a simple yet working code for this ? I would rather prefer python but any language would work. how can i use seqeuence ?

Comment: It would be the above which works. You must be doing something wrong elsewhere. See my previous comment.

Comment: I have solved the issue. The problem fixed when i entered Sequence data for every single object rather than just the one that i want.